# Mod_rewrite condition that will accept + in string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So first, I promise I've looked everywhere but I'm either not finding the right answer or not knowing I found that right answer and moved on (possible). I have some strings that might contain one or more words that are spaced with a + inside my normal page which would look like this       http://beaneandco.com/pageTESTING.php?name=Boys+Shirt. This page works fine except it's dirty. I wrote a rewrite code that cleans this up.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$ pageTESTING.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])/$ pageTESTING.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If my page is just one word, as in Boys, it works just fine when shortened. For whatever reason though, when it has two words or more seperated by a + it no longer works. There is a GET at the beginning of my page that has this string if that changes anything. So.........what in the world am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the regexp code the +, space and other characters you have in URL.

Try this in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\+ \-])$ pageTESTING.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\+ \-])/$ pageTESTING.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```